# jQuery slideToggle HTML lists with same classes

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-lists, slidetoggle

I have parent list items, which contain child list items.

I cannot amend the CSS for this, the CSS is the same for each child list, hence the problem.

When using slideToggle, once two or more child lists are toggled, the previous opened lists do not close as all the classes are the same. (note, I cannot amend this...)

What is the best way to handle this logic: If one child list is opened and another parent is clicked, close the previous opened toggled child lists?

**Reduced test case:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vENQyN

```
$( "li.has-children" ).click(function() {

    $(this).addClass('open-me');

    $( ".open-me ul.children" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
        $(".has-children").removeClass('open-me');
    });

  return false;

});

});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save the last open item in a "global" variable and before opening the new one, close the previouse one. Something like this:

```
if (previouseOpened && previouseOpened.jquery) {
  previouseOpened.removeClass('open-me');
} 
 previouseOpened = $(this);
```

By the way, if you need more explanation please tell me and I'll do so

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/empQGQ

Check the link ;)

Comment: I somewhat get this, but am not sure where to place this in the above example for best practice? In the slideToggle complete?

Comment: Ah, only one issue I see. If you open then try to close the same item, it re-opens, not closes.

Comment: You should add `|| $(this).is(previouseOpened)` on the pre-conditional if. Updated code is [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/empQGQ)

Comment: your codepen appears to not be working with that update, locally for me it jolts back to the closed position correctly, but without a smooth animation.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {


    $( "li.has-children" ).click(function() {



        $( this ).children('ul').slideToggle( "slow");
    $( this ).siblings().children('ul').slideUp( "slow");
    });

  });
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kwdrmo

EDIT:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {

    $( "li" ).click(function(e) {

e.stopPropagation();

        $( this ).children('ul').slideToggle( "slow");
    $( this ).siblings().children('ul').slideUp( "slow");
    });



  });
```

Now it should work, hopefully. :)

Comment: This and the working example look to be just right, I'll test this more today. Thank you.

Comment: One problem with this is if you expand a child item, then click a child li link, it does not follow the link, it closes the expanded list which is wrong.

Comment: exactly, the below solution incorporated it http://stackoverflow.com/a/27278126/4034148 - thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I exactly understand what you are trying to do but you could try to close all other parent items except the one you clicked.

```
$( "li.has-children" ).click(function() {

    $(this).addClass('open-me');

    //Here you could use slideUp() instead of hide() if you prefer to have an animation.
    $("li.has-children").not(this).find("ul.children").hide();

    $( ".open-me ul.children" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
        $(".has-children").removeClass('open-me');
    });

    return false;
});
```

Hope this help!

Comment: That does not work for me, some child list items open at random when others are clicked. Also clicking child li items, closes the entire child ul item.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( "li.has-children" ).click(function() {
    if($(".open-me"))
        $(".open-me").removeClass('open-me');

    $(this).addClass('open-me');
    $( ".open-me ul.children" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
        //other things
    });

    return false;
});
```